# ClearDB MySQL Installation on Heroku Asking for Account Verification

Tags: mysql, heroku, cleardb

I have deployed my current Laravel project on **Heroku**. My local database is MySQL. As Heroku does not support MySQL directly, I need to install **ClearDB** **MySQL** addon. When I run **`heroku addons:create cleardb:ignite`** in my Heroku CLI, it gives the following message:

```
> Please verify your account to install this add-on plan (please enter a
> credit card)
```

Is this verification a must?
Can anyone help me install this addon free!

Answer (score 10):

I was also stuck in this barrier and found this question unanswered, you may have realized that is not possible to add most of the addons without billing information. The reasons is <s>hidden</s> stated in the documentation about [Account Verification](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification#when-is-verification-required):

> When is verification required?
>   You must verify your account if you, or collaborators of your app, want to:
>
> - Use more than one dyno in the app.
> - Add any add-on to the app, even if the add-on is free. The only exceptions to this are the free plans for the Heroku Postgres and Heroku Connect add-ons, which can be added without verification.
> - Add a custom domain to the app.
> - Receive the transfer of an app that has paid resources.
> - Exceed default one-off dyno limits on the app.
> - Have more than 5 apps at a time. Verified accounts may have up to 100 apps.

It also says that verifying an account means that you MUST add a credit card.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use add-ons without a credit card on Heroku. This to prevent creation of many accounts only to get many free add-ons.